# Trying to convert json to array - cannot read 'length' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have json coming down as props into my page, I need to convert the json into an array to use with my google chart component. Can anyone help?

Currently get the error:

**Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

In `componentdidmount` i have:

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    this.dataToChartArray();
},
```

My `dataToChartArray`:

```
dataToChartArray: function(){

    var chartData = [['Attendance', 'Percentage']];

    // loop through props, append to array..

    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.sectionData.attendanceTotals.length; i++) {
        chartData.push([this.props.sectionData.attendanceTotals[i].description,
            this.props.sectionData.attendanceTotals[i].percentage]);
    }

    // set state with new chart data
    this.setState({
        chartData: chartData
    });

},`

dataToChartArray: function(){

    var chartData = [['Attendance', 'Percentage']];



    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.sectionData.attendanceTotals.length; i++) {
        chartData.push([this.props.sectionData.attendanceTotals[i].description,
            this.props.sectionData.attendanceTotals[i].percentage]);
    }

    this.setState({
        chartData: chartData
    });

},
```

Then in my chart jsx I have:

```
     <Chart chartType="PieChart"
                   data={this.state.chartData}
                   options = {options}
            />
```

Then my getStatsChart:

```
getStatsChart: function(){

    var options = {
            legend:'none',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            chartArea: {
                left: "3%",
                top: "3%",
                height: "100%",
                width: "100%"
            },
            backgroundColor: '#eee',
            is3D: true
            };

        return (

            <Chart chartType="PieChart"

                   data={this.state.chartData}
                   options = {options}
            />
        );

},
```

Comment: Please show us the content of "this.props.sectionData"

Comment: What it's trying to tell you is that `attendanceTotals` is null